# Container View not Satisfying AutoLayout

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicontainerview

I just learned how to use container views, and I am running into an annoying issue.

What I simply have is a container view that is at the bottom of the screen along with its constraints 
[image]

Container is linked to GraphScrollableViewController. Then, from my MainViewController containing the container, I simply pass data to the container like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destination = segue.destinationViewController

    if let gvc = destination as? GraphScrollableViewController {
        if segue.identifier == "graphViewControllerSegue" {
            gvc.categoryPrices = categoryPrices
            gvc.categoryTimes = categoryTimes
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the GraphScrollableViewController is simply [GraphView-Scrollable Library](https://github.com/philackm/Scrollable-GraphView). It uses the full screen of the view, and is scrollable right and left.

Now, I get the final result below, which doesn't satisfy autolayout constraints (it's not supposed to be to beyond the main screen view.)

Any help to solve that would be appreciated :)

[image]

EDIT: 
In GraphScrollableViewController, the way I make the graph cover the whole view of the container is like this:

```
let graphView = ScrollableGraphView(frame: self.view.frame)
```

And this is GraphScrollableViewController: 
[image]

When adding a view inside the container and setting
`let graphView = ScrollableGraphView(frame: self.viewInContainer.frame)`
It s better except the right side which still overflows

[image]
[image]

Comment: What are constraints of the `GraphScrollableViewController`? You need to pin edges of that view to the container view.

Comment: @user1941284 Can you explain more what you mean? I also added a piece of info in the question if it helps

Comment: I think that container view is placed correctly on the screen, but view from `GraphScrollableViewController` is not placed correctly in the container view. Can you inspect view hierarchy?

Comment: @user1941284 added screenshot of the `GraphScrollableViewController`.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html Try to find out which view is not placed correctly by inspection of view hierarchy.

Comment: Cool tool btw! It seems ScrollableGraphView suddenly has its bounds outside of the view for some reason. Will investigate. in the meantime, tried to add another view in container (you can see edit in the question for the result)

Comment: Have you tried with my answer? also put that after viewDidLoad

Comment: yeah i tried it before, didn't work..

Comment: Why don't you add `ScrollableGraphView` in xib file, just drag `UIView` and change class to the `ScrollableGraphView` and pin edges to the superview.

Comment: I can try that. I was initially just interested in seeing how container views work :)